# Difference between fread from storage and fread from url PHP

Tags: php, file, fopen, fread, chunks

When I use **fread** in **PHP** to **read files** and **chunks files** from **storage** and from **URL** the results are not the same.

Code example chunks file from storage:

```
// Filesize of filename.png - 5,8MB
$fp = fopen('path to local storage/filename.png', 'r');

$segment_id = 0;

while (!feof($fp)) {
  $chunk = fread($fp, 1048576); // 1MB per chunk for this sample
  echo $segment_id;
  $segment_id++;
}
```

Result when echo $segment_id: `012345`

---

Code example chunks file from URL:

```
// Filesize of filename.png - 5,8MB
$fp = fopen('https://example.com/filename.png', 'r');

$segment_id = 0;

while (!feof($fp)) {
  $chunk = fread($fp, 1048576); // 1MB per chunk for this sample
  echo $segment_id;
  $segment_id++;
}
```

Result when echo $segment_id: A lot more than that file from local storage

The desired result is that the chunk file from **URL** will be the same as the chunk file from storage

Comment: your output is the counter for the loop, reading the file, not the content of the file. as written here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php ."if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file, at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size (usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size." you cant know, how many bytes fread returns. why do you need the counter ?

Comment: I'm using for Twitter API upload media, so do you know how to read the file from the url to give results like storage?